# Creating calculated column based on values of other column in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, measure

I need help in creating a calculated column and don't know where to start.

So I have a dataset with Portfolio, Project, Reporting Date, Status as columns.

| Portfolio | Project | Reporting Date | Status | Time to Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data | AAAA | 01 Apr 2023 | Started | 0 |
| Data | AAAA | 01 May 2023 | Completed | 1 |
| Data | AAAA | 01 Jun 2023 | On Track | 0 |
| Data | AAAA | 01 Jul 2023 | Completed | 1 |
| Data | BBBB | 01 Apr 2023 | Completed | 0 |
| Data | BBBB | 01 May 2023 | Started | 0 |
| Data | BBBB | 01 Jun 2023 | Completed | 1 |
| Data | BBBB | 01 Jul 2023 | Completed | 0 |
| Data | CCCC | 01 Apr 2023 | Completed | 0 |
| Data | CCCC | 01 May 2023 | Started | 0 |
| Data | CCCC | 01 Jun 2023 | Started | 0 |
| Data | CCCC | 01 Jul 2023 | Completed | 2 |

What I want to calculate is the Time to Completed column, which is how long it took the status to turn to Completed. For example for the first project, it went from started to completed after 1 month in May and July, and for the second project it went Completed after 1 month in June, and similarly it took 2 months for the status to go to Green for the 3rd project.

For the second project, since the month after (July) was also "Completed", the Time to completed remains at 0. 
Also for the month in Apr in the same project the status is "Completed" but since that is the first entry that is recorded, there is no other Completed status to compare to hence why it is 0.

How would I do this?

Comment: Is a column missing? How do you know which record a completion date belongs to? you have two "completed" records for project AAAA: one on 1-May and another on 1-July. is it safe to assume start is MIN(ReportingDate) and end is MAX(ReportingDate)?

Comment: Thats right @Pieter, the status changes every month for each project

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in that case you don't need to filter for Portfolio in your measure...

```
Latest End Date = 
MAXX(
    FILTER('ProjectProgress', 
      [Status]="Completed"),
[Reporting Date]
    )

Earliest Start Date =
MINX(
    FILTER('ProjectProgress', 
      [Status]="Started"),
[Reporting Date]
    )
```

Then the INT([Latest End Date] - [Earliest Start Date]) still stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

This should work across Portfolios (assuming you can have two projects with the same name, but in different portfolios).

```
Earliest Start Date = 
MINX(
    FILTER('ProjectProgress',
        [Portfolio] = MAX([Portfolio]) && 
        [Status]="Started"),
[Reporting Date]
    )
```

and then the other bookend:

```
Latest End Date = 
MAXX(
    FILTER('ProjectProgress',
    [Portfolio] = MAX([Portfolio]) && 
      [Status]="Completed"),
[Reporting Date]
    )
```

and then you just subtract to get the duration in days:

```
Work Duration = 
INT([Latest End Date]-[Earliest Start Date])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! 

Each project will have a different name, so no two projects are the same